Win11 WSL2, How to verify `networkingMode=mirrored` is effective?
In MSDN article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/networking#mirrored-mode-networking , he says that there is a new setting in .wslconfig, networkingMode=mirrored.
By his statement, with mirrored mode enabled: If the Windows host runs a TCP server, then WSL Linux instance can connect to that TCP server using localhost(127.0.0.1) as destination address.
However, I cannot reproduce/verify that statement, anything wrong? See my screenshot below.
And I hope there is a instant way to verify whether the networkingMode=mirrored is recognized by WSL engine, maybe some query command or so. Is there？


instant way to verify whether the networkingMode=mirrored is recognized is the ip address of eth0 in WSL the same as your IP address in windows? If so, then networkingMode is indeed mirrored - your failure to connect to 127.0.0.1 from WSL is some other issue - rather than listening on 0.0.0.0:7773 try listening on 127.0.0.1:7773 - I found using 0.0.0.0 on the windows side does not work as expected w.r.t. 127.0.0.1

I would agree this is a Python 0.0.0.0 listening to issue rather than a WSL network mirroring issue. You can very the version of WSL and the kernel installed to determine if network mirroring is in effect. Of course instead of localhost or 0.0.0.0 I would connect to Windows from WSL on the intranet address of the host adapter. It could also be a python script problem, reverse the connection and enable localhostForwarding, and connect Windows to WSL.

@JaromandaX ipconfig says My Windows host vEthernet has IP=172.28.240.1/20, which is different than the IP of the WSL2 instance(172.28.240.56/20). If the two IPs are the same, it would be WSL1 -- AFAIK. That python script is simple and I tested it, no problem.  https://github.com/chjfth/dailytools/blob/master/pytools/tcpechoserv.py

@JaromandaX You mean I should have WSL telnet connect to 172.28.240.1, BUT that's not my intention, because that always succeeds, even if networkingMode=NAT (default behavior), no need to verify it again. And, you know, I want to verify the effect of networkingMode=mirrored.

I'm using mirrored mode - in WSL, my IP address is identical to the windows one - that's what mirrored mode does. So, clearly, the problem is that you are not running in networkingMode=mirrored - also, the fact that you have a vEthernet on windows and your WSL is on the same subnet means you are not running mirrored - the rest of my comment is observations that depending on how the service is running, localhost and/or 127.0.0.1 may not work from WSL in mirrored mode, and is relatively unimportant, since you are not in mirrored mode anyway

That python script is simple and I tested it, no problem - how do you know, since you didn't even use mirrored mode to test it?

@JaromandaX You should correct your idea. I can verify the py script in a normal(non WSL) environment, and it accepts TCP client as expected. The correctness of the py script has nothing to do with WSL's NAT mode or mirrored mode.

@JimmChen you say that - wait until you get mirrored mode working - I'm not saying you will have the issue I described, I'm saying you MAY

Got it. That's due to my original WSL engine version too old. That old engine does NOT support mirrored mode.
So, I need to update WSL engine.
I run wsl --update, and see that uname -r output changes from 5.10.16.3 to 5.15.153.1 --probably the Linux kernel version number. That means the update takes effect.
After this update, inside WSL2, we get new command wslinfo .

wslinfo --wsl-version shows WSL engine version, now 2.2.4 .
wslinfo --networking-mode shows nat or mirrored. Now we users finally have a way to verify the setting from .wslconfig.

Now, WSL2 mirrored mode works as MSDN has stated. My screen shot below.


Hint: To switch from 'nat' to 'mirrored', we need to execute wsl --shutdown to ensure that the WSL engine has fully shutdown. Then the new WSL instance will respect the value in .wslconfig.
